# Cannot set column to NOT NULL in Visual Studio 2012, Error: An error occurred while the batch was being executed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] 
(
    [UserId]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Gender]     CHAR (10)      NULL,
    [Vegetarian] BIT            NULL,
    [Diet]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Birthday] SMALLDATETIME NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);
```

and I cannot update the database if I set a column to `NOT NULL`, or uncheck the `Allow Null` checkbox in the design mode. VS returns this error:

> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

No other information is given. Someone please explain this to me. I want `UserName`, `Gender`, and `Email` as `NOT NULL`.

---

UPDATE: I found out where the problem is. The sample users of my program does not have any data, that's why when I set new columns to `NOT NULL`, errors occur.

Comment: If the table already contains `null` values in those columns then it won't be able to make that change.  More specifically, there must be information about the error *somewhere*.  Perhaps in another window in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query to locate the erroneous rows:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UserProfile]
WHERE UserName is NULL OR Gender is NULL or Email is NULL
```

You will probably have to run an update such as this before changing each column:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[UserProfile]
SET Email = N' '
WHERE Email is NULL
```

**Don't** try to combine the updates for the columns - you will run the risk of overwriting correct column values.